# in gridview adapter class imageview set wrap content the images are blink while running in android?

Tags: android, gridview

I Created custom grid view with product list based on web service(json).but i facing new issue.when i set size(100dp) for image view height & width it working perfectly.but i set wrap_content or match parent it's view images are blink & blink again..

my fragment class :

```
public class HorizontalAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private ArrayList<HomeCategoriesData> mArrayList;
    private Context mContext;
    private LayoutInflater mLayoutInflater;

    public HorizontalAdapter(Activity homeActivity, ArrayList<HomeCategoriesData> mArrayList) {

        this.mContext = homeActivity;
        this.mArrayList = mArrayList;
        mLayoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    }
@Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mArrayList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return mArrayList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        ViewHolder mViewHolder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            mViewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            convertView = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.item_categories_item, null);
            mViewHolder.mTvName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_categories_name);
            mViewHolder.mIvimage = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.iv_categories_img);

            convertView.setTag(mViewHolder);

        } else {
            mViewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

       mViewHolder.mTvName.setText(mArrayList.get(position).getName());
        Picasso.with(mContext).load(mArrayList.get(position).getCat_img()).into(mViewHolder.mIvimage);
        convertView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Toast.makeText(mContext,mArrayList.get(position).getName(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                //calling fragment from adatper class...

              SellerSubCategoryFragment frag = new SellerSubCategoryFragment();
                FragmentManager fm = ((MainActivity)mContext).getSupportFragmentManager();

                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putString("id", String.valueOf(mArrayList.get(position).getId()));
                frag.setArguments(bundle);
                fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame,frag).addToBackStack(null).commit();
 }
        });
return convertView;
    }
private class ViewHolder {
        TextView mTvName;
        ImageView mIvimage;
    }
}
```

my adapter class xml file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_categories_img"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter" />
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_categories_name"
        style="@android:style/TextAppearance.Small"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_top_categories_name_5"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:lines="1"
        android:textColor="@color/black" />
</LinearLayout>
```

my out put issue are ,
[image]

[image]

so what i do? and what is the problem.why i cannot set wrap_content or match_parent in this grid view?. my custom grid view are **ExpandapleHeightGridView**

[image]

[image]

Comment: try to change :  if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.item_categories_item,parent,false);
   mViewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            mViewHolder.mTvName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_categories_name);
            mViewHolder.mIvimage = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.iv_categories_img);
            convertView.setTag(mViewHolder);
        } else {
            mViewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

Comment: and make ViewHolder class Static

Comment: now blink issue solved.but images position are wrong & view also wrong.i update images.check it now

Comment: where? i do not see any change

Comment: public Object getItem(int i) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return 0;
    }

Comment: sorry i don't understand.explain please

Comment: did you try to change above methods ?

Comment: why i change get item values?

Comment: it not affect your implementation just check it one time

Comment: but the get item values are used for load data's in arraylist size.are you sure to change null???

Comment: yes and also change getItemId value to 0

Comment: i changed that.

Comment: thanks.it work perfectly.i want to know why this issue happen?please tell me?

Comment: i don't know exact behavior, because i use recyclerview for listing. rarely use BaseAdapter.

Comment: i having facing another issue.check 10 inch tab the first item position are changed.other items correct position.but first item are below 10dp compare to normal

Comment: i suggest you to use recyclerview for this. it is best for performance

Comment: but i need gridview not recycler view.

Comment: you can set grid in recyclerview easily.

Comment: how????????????

Comment: you used recyclerview before?